# How to split values in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, file, split

I have a CSV file which looks like below. Right now it doesn't have any columns and it contains some fields I actually don't need so I need to write it into a new file based on some conditions.

```
!PROJECT1, OBJECT1
2020-09-10+02:00,100,HHH,SAS,RM$20,1,1
2020-09-16+02:00,200,GGG,SAS,TAKE,2020-09-16+02:00
2020-09-13+02:00,300,TTT,SAS,TAKE,2020-09-13+02:00
2020-09-11+02:00,100,HHH,SAS,RM$20,1,1
```

**These are the conditions:**

1. I will only write the record if `index[4]` contains the word `TAKE`. If so, take `index[0]`, `[4]` and `[5]`.
2. Index[0] and [5] need to be spitted and named in `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` and `TD`. `index[4]` needs to be named `TYPE`

**I want my new file to look like this:**

```
YEAR    MONTH    DAY    TD    TYPE    YEAR    MONTH    DAY    TD 
2020    09       16     2     TAKE     2020    09       16     2
2020    09       13     2     TAKE     2020    09       13     2
```

**This is my code:**

```
def filter_row(r):
    condition_1 = r[4] == 'TAKE' #<-- take only the TAKE's

with open(file_path, 'r') as my_file, open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outer:
        reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter = ',')
        next(reader) #Skip the first row because it's just the header
        writer = csv.writer(outer, delimiter = '\t')
        for row in reader:            
                if filter_row(row):
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Right now my output file looks like this:

```
2020-09-16+02:00,  200,  GGG,   SAS,  TAKE,  2020-09-16+02:00
2020-09-13+02:00,  300,  TTT,   SAS,  TAKE,  2020-09-13+02:00
```

Comment: use ```pandas```. much easier.

Comment: @YashShah have been told to use CSV because I have more then 35000 rows and more then 25 columns

Comment: `r[4] is 'TAKE'` - you should use `==` instead of `is` here.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/1504717/3282436

Comment: @0x5453 True, I've changed it but what about the rest?

Answer (score 1):

There are two tasks here. Firstly, filter the data, secondly parse the data to get the required values.

Filtering can be done with the built-in [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function (or a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) if you prefer).  For the parsing a small function can be used as we need to process two dates per row.

[operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is used to extract data from rows efficiently.

```
import csv
import operator

# Get the value of the 'take' column
type_getter = operator.itemgetter(4)
# Extract the columns we want to work with
columns_getter = operator.itemgetter(0, 4, 5)


def process_datestring(datestring):
    # Assumes offset is always positive; consider
    # using re.split if it could be positive or negative.
    date, _, offset = datestring.partition('+')
    dateparts = date.split('-')
    td, *_ = offset.partition(':')
    dateparts.append(td)
    return dateparts


headers = ['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'TD', 'TYPE', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'TD']
with open(file_path, 'r') as my_file, open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outer:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader) #Skip the first row because it's just the header
    writer = csv.writer(outer, delimiter = '\t')

    writer.writerow(headers)

    filtered = filter(lambda r: type_getter(r) == 'TAKE', reader)
    for row in filtered:
        date1, type_, date2 = columns_getter(row)
        out_row = process_datestring(date1)
        out_row.append(type_)
        out_row.extend(process_datestring(date2))
        writer.writerow(out_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a parse function. Something like this:

```
def parser(row):
    if "TAKE" in row[4]: #Checks for your 'TAKE' statement
        year = row[0][0:4]
        month = row[0][5:7]
        ...
        year_2 = row[5][0:4]
        ...
        return [year, month, day, td, row[4], year_2, month_2,...]
```

And just give this whole thing to your writer:

```
for row in reader:
    converted = parser(row)
    writer.writerow(converted)
```

This should work. If you want to be more carefull, you will have to convert the string to a `datetime.datetime` object using `strptime` and then extract the dates, but if chopping the string is good enough, you could do this.

Comment: Its not giving the desired output. I still get all the rows and nothing is splitted.